# creating ansible playbook to install vnc

Tags: ansible, vnc

How would you go about to write an ansible playbook to install vnc on a remote server?. I am using ubuntu 18.04, i have ansible installed and have ran a playbook to install nginx an it successfully work

```
 ---
    - hosts : test-server
      become: true
      vars:
        ansible_become_pass:"password"
      tasks :
     - name : install nginx
       package : pkg=nginx state=installed

       notify:
        - start nginx

       handlers :
        - name : start nginx
          service : name=nginx state=started
```

How can i refactor this or what should i add to install vnc. I am using ubuntu 18.04, ansible version 2.5.1

Answer (score 2):

To answer the first question, I wouldn't write the whole thing by myself to begin with. Lot of people already did it, for example you can try this role https://galaxy.ansible.com/sdarwin/vnc, or look at its sources for some inspiration.

But if it's about improving the playbook as you started it, well, find a tutorial about installing the VNC server you're aiming at (tightvncserver, tigervnc, ...?), then translate the bash commands to Ansible. `apt install something` translate to `package: pkg=something state=installed` , etc.